# How to change the default database count to another number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

The default database count is zero.
So how can it be changed to another number like 1000 or 10000 ?

I am using a plugin called [CFDB](https://cfdbplugin.com/) in WordPress and if I want to get my result, I should add 1000 empty values to get it.

Is there any easier way to change it ?

Comment: Wouldn't an `UPDATE` statement work?

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

Comment: paste columns definition here. It looks like your table haven't AUTOINC feature